# Making restrictions in a SQL program using triggers

Tags: mysql

I am working these days on a program on mySQL workbench. I have created the following tables:

```
create table if not exists customers
(
customerId varchar(10) primary key,
customerAFM varchar(9) not null,
first_name text not null,
surname text not null,
sex varchar(8),
birthdate date,
address text,
phone_number varchar(10)
) engine = innodb;

create table if not exists employees
(
employeeId varchar(5) primary key,
first_name text not null,
surname text not null,
specialty text not null,
address text,
phone_number varchar(10)
) engine = innodb;

create table if not exists rooms
(
room_number int primary key,
capacity int not null,
category text
) engine = innodb;

create table if not exists accomodation
(
accomodationId varchar(5) primary key,
room_number int not null, #constraint acc_num foreign key references rooms(room_number),
start_date date,
end_date date,
accomodation_price float, 
foreign key (room_number) references rooms (room_number)
);

create table if not exists accomodation_customers
(  
accomodationId varchar(5) primary key,
customerId varchar(5) not null unique key,
foreign key (accomodationId) references accomodation (accomodationId),
foreign key (customerId) references customers (customerId)
);

create table if not exists products
(
productId varchar(15) primary key,
product_name text,
product_price int
) engine = InnoDB;

create table if not exists charges
(
customerId varchar(5) primary key,
productId varchar(15) not null unique key,
charge_date datetime not null unique key,
employeeId varchar(5) not null,
quantity float,
foreign key (customerId) references customers (customerId),
foreign key (productId) references products (productId),
foreign key (employeeId) references employees (employeeId)
);

create table if not exists availability
(
registrationId int auto_increment primary key,
all_rooms int, 
available_rooms int,
completeness float
);
```

Now, what I want to do is to make the restriction that follows using trigger:
It must not be possible to stay in the same room a number of customers that overcomes the capacity of the room. For example, in case a room was double then it can not be feasible more than 2 people to stay in this room.

How can I make it real?

Comment: table customers, products, employees are not related to your question, you can remove them to keep your question short.  Regarding your question, you can add a trigger on accomodation_customers which calculates the number of customers in the related rooms to see if capacity is exceeded and throw an error if true.

Comment: But how...? I guess I have to connect somehow the room_number and the capacity(which the rooms table contains) with the customerId (which the accomodation_customers table contains). I have thought of joining the 2 tables, but I do not know anything for sure. I just have to do it. However, thank you Tim3880 for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be too long for comment.

You may still want to take a look at your schema design:

1) table "availability" is something you may not need.

2) do you really want to use a varchar(5) for the accomodationID or customerId?

3) table "accomodation_customers" is not good for  one-to-many or many-to-many relationships, and you may want to change it to :

```
 create table if not exists accomodation_customers
 (  
 accomodationId varchar(5) not null,
 customerId varchar(5) not null ,
 primary key (accomodationId, customerId),
 foreign key (accomodationId) references accomodation (accomodationId),
 foreign key (customerId) references customers (customerId)
 );
```

Then you can check the availability and status of each room for a specified date:

```
set @date:=date_add(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
select room_number, capacity, (select count(customerid) from accomodation a
join accomodation_customers r
on a.accomodationId  = r.accomodationId
where a.start_date < cast(@date as date)
and a.end_date > @date
and a.room_number = rooms.room_number
)  occupied 
from rooms;
```

If you do it in your trigger, you can throw an exception there and kill the transaction if the occupied is bigger than capacity of any room.

Booking/reserving logic are usually very complicated and you can't solve it all with one trigger. You need check the availability before you add any accommodation. You can add "number of persons" column in your accommodation table and make things easier:

```
set @date:=date_add(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
select room_number, capacity, (select sum(number_of_persons) from accomodation a
where a.start_date < cast(@date as date)
and a.end_date > @date
and a.room_number = rooms.room_number
)  occupied from rooms;
```

and the trigger can be added on the "accommodation table".

Again, hotels usually don't let different customers share one room. So logically the capacities and "numbers of persons" are usually "1".